# Check XML against DTD using only pl/sql

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, dtd

I have a stored procedure that receives a XML inside of a CLOB, and I store the data contained in to to a table using a

INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT (...) 
FROM XMLTABLE(...)

my question is, there's a way to check the receiving XML against a DTD (and a XSD too if possible) using only PL/SQL?

I can't do that from the sender side nor have database privileges to add new tools to the database server.

Also, if you know a more proper/efficient way to insert that data on a table?

I'm using Oracle 11.2 btw

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can validate against a schema doc.  I would suggest start reading the XML DB docs - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/xmldb/overview/index.html